# jQuery Word Export File is not a valid web archive error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-word

I'm using the jQuery Word Export plugin to download some HTML as a word document but when I try and open the document in Word on Mac, I get File is not a valid web archive error.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: I also facing the same issue in Mac machine. Working fine in Windows.

Comment: i am facing same issue in mac but working fine in window .please help me